R function/package to find frequent consecutive patterns in bunch of sequences
So let's say I have a bunch of sequences consisting in series of numbers going from 1 to 25. (for example (x<- (1,16,2,2,3,6,18,16)). I just want to find in all those sequences if there is frequent patterns that come back a lot. Like, if I enter prob_min = 0.5 and seq_min = 2, I would need a program that send me back all the subsequences 2-number long or longer, which are present in at least 20% of the sequences. The program should also send me the percentage of sequences in which we found this subsequence.
What I call a frequent subsequence is a consecutive serie of number. In the example x higher, (1,16,2) is a subsequence, (2,3,6,18) is a subsequence, but (1,2,2) is not because they are not consecutive.
I tried using packages like Traminer or arulesSequence but they don't take into account the consecutive part of what I want.
